# Comunication between Express.js and PHP through jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, express

I'm developing a small project where I have a web page (index.html) loading in Express.js and it sends some data to a PHP script running on a MAMP server. The PHP script processes the data and returns a JSON encoded array back to the web page and finally the Node.js server sends data to connected clients using socket.io.

I have problems with the communication with PHP using jQuery Ajax. I send the data to PHP using POST and I know PHP receives that data but I don't know how to catch the response from PHP to know how the processing went.

I have no experience with Node.js. What can I do to make this thing work?

So far this is the code I have

**Node.js - Express.js**

```
    var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , db = require('./routes/db')
  , http = require('http')
  , socketio = require('socket.io')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser()); //Middleware
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**HTML Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="formContainer">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="text" name="texto">
          <button type="button" id="buttonSend">Enviar</button>
        </form><br/><br/>      
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$('#buttonSend').click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/NodePHP/test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {value: 1},
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success == true){
                alert("Perfect!");
            }
            else{
                alert("Error!");   
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            //alert("Error de llamada al servidor");
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            //$('#botonUsarFoto').css('display','block');
        }
    });         
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

$number = $_POST['value'];
echo $number;

// move the image into the specified directory //
if ($number == 1) {
    $data = array("success"=>"true");
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $data = array("success"=>"false");
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you see `json object` in `console`?

Comment: @RohanKumar No. I'm using Firebug and I see the data sent to PHP but the response is completely empty and the $.ajax code always executes the `error: function(xhr,status,error)` block.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a request with Node, we'll use the `http` and `querystring` modules.  Here's an example lovingly adopted from [the Nodejitsu folks](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request):

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var data = querystring.stringify({
  value: 1
});

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/myPHPScript',
  method: 'POST'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Alternatively, you could use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, but first things first.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this code but PHP doesn't get the value posted. It always gets NULL.
In case it worked, it isn't clear for me how I could integrate this request with the jQuery Ajax code I already have in my HTML page.